# Cannot boot from the Rufus created USB Ubuntu stick

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell, rufus

I get error messages in black screen. Timeouts and errors. The error on my Windows XP Dell D830 laptop looks very similar as seen in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/1hMWySNdegg). The Dell D830 laptop has a dual-core Intel processor with 64-bit support.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information!

Comment: Hello DK Bose, I am just following the "create a bootable USB stick on Windows" at tutorials.ubuntu.com. I have a 4GB USB stick, but now I see it has bootx64.efi, while I have a 32 laptop. So how to get the 32 edition on the USB stick?

Comment: The error on my windows XP Dell D830 Laptop looks very similar as seen in the video from Karel, he writes about the same issue some 4 minutes ago

Comment: Found the 32bit format and will try again

Comment: I looked up the specs on the Dell D830 laptop and it says that there are 3 models of this laptop. Two models come with NVIDA graphics and one model has only integrated Mobile Intel GMA X3100 graphics. Which graphics does your Dell D830 laptop have, NVIDIA or Intel integrated graphics? I rerfreshed my memory by watching that video again and it looks like NVIDIA graphics glitching to me.

Answer (score -1):

I also come across such difficulty. it is just simple. install the OS in the USB in DD Image file instead of ISO file and try to install.